# Why can't I include the string library in C++?

Tags: c++

This is a short one.

There's a fatal error:
No library titled "string" or something like that.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  //[insert code here]
}
```

It should be correct, I looked how to use strings and this is exactly what to do.

Comment: Is _"or something like that"_ the actual compiler output?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's not, I just don't exactly remember what it said.

Comment: you need to check the selected compiler and it's configurations from the IDE settings also make sure to inculde the iostream library that may works sometimes I still need the actual compiler error output to be more precise with my answer but you could try what I suggest to you

Comment: I just figured it out. I used a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.

Comment: Voting to close the question as a typo / not reproducible.

Comment: C ≠ C++

Easy peasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are compiling it with a `c++` compiler. Using a C compiler for C++ code may produce confusing error messages just like the one you got.